# keras error got an unexpected keyword argument 'epochs'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train a network in Keras to classify an image and after debugging the last issue got this one of unexpected keywork epochs

```
muiruri_samuel@training-2:~/google-landmark-recognition-challenge$ python train.py
Using TensorFlow backend.
Found 981214 images belonging to 14951 classes.
Found 237925 images belonging to 14951 classes.
Epoch 1/1
2018-03-15 13:35:19.822304: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instruc
tions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 74, in <module>
    validation_data=validation_generator)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in w
rapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 1276, in fit_genera
tor
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in w
rapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 2224, in f
it_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1883, in t
rain_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/home/muiruri_samuel/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line
 2478, in __call__
    **self.session_kwargs)
TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'epochs'
```

at this point I've removed epochs but still getting the same error

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 150, 150

train_data_dir = 'training_images'
validation_data_dir = 'validation_images'
nb_train_samples = 2000
nb_validation_samples = 800
epochs = 50
batch_size = 16

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(14951, activation="softmax"))

monitor = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=1e-3, patience=5, verbose=0, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath="best_weights.hdf5", verbose=0, save_best_only=True) # save best model

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', callbacks=[monitor,checkpointer], epochs=1000, metrics=['accuracy'])

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for training
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1. / 255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True)

# this is the augmentation configuration we will use for testing:
# only rescaling
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    validation_data=validation_generator)

model.load_weights('best_weights.hdf5') # load weights from best model
model.save('last_model.h5')
```

I'd use epochs and batches too but now I'd need it to work first. The model in logic has a folder `training_images` which has sub folders which are the the classes of the images with the images in these sub folders. Then there's the `validation_images` which is randomly sampled 20% of the training images to validation.

Comment: it was in the fit but i've also seen another in the compile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`model.compile` does not take an epochs parameter. Only `fit` and `fit_generator` do.

Comment: Does `.evaluate()` takes epochs as input?